# What is the correct order of verb - modifer - subject?

Tags: grammar, syntax

Dummy question here, but would it be "pick up [an item] or pick [an item] up? Appreciate any help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with writing.

Comment: There is **no** "correct" word order here. Firstly, English is an extraordinarily flexible language, and both usages are common. There's an old-fashioned opprobrium against ending a sentence with a preposition, but few worry about that nowadays. Secondly, there **cannot** be a rule for purely creative writing, since any content is a matter of artistic expression, personal style, etc. If you want the meaning to be unambiguous and easily understood, then orthodoxy in syntax, spelling and punctuation is useful – but not all writing is so intended :-)

Answer (score 1):

People say both, at least in US English. But if you consider "pick up" as a phrase that means as get, raise, or take, then logically the two words should stay together.

But -- English allows variation for emphasis. Prepositions in some prepositional phrases can be separated without becoming gibberish. You can split infinitives in English. You can do a lot of things that are right in some cases and wrong in others. You can "lift up your spirit" or "lift your spirit up" if you are preaching to a crowd.

According to an excellent explanation on this site (https://jakubmarian.com/splitting-phrasal-verb-and-preposition-particle-in-english/)...

"There are in fact two types of phrasal verbs, the so called prepositional phrasal verbs, e.g. “look after someone”, and particle phrasal verbs, e.g. “let someone down”. The terminology here is somewhat unfortunate, and in fact, linguists usually do not call the first type “phrasal verbs”.

So, you can "pick something up" but you can't "look something after." Some phrases with a preposition can be split, and some become nonsense if they are split. "Pick up" can be split and still be completely understandable.

Comment: Hello, user8356. Excellent, excellent input. You answered all my questions (and even some I didn't even know I had until went to the link you so kindly provided.) Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, Jan. Isn't English fun? Please mark this as an accepted answer if you can!